# Visual Studio 2012 - Cannot package my Azure App

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure

I'm trying to generate the package for my Azure app, but I keep getting the following error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users..\AppData\Local\Temp\mpwgheuv.lqw\roles\MessageBoard_WebRole\approot\Default.aspx' is denied.

I don't think it's a problem with permissions. I opened the Temp folder and noticed during packaging, the above directory gets created and then removed instantly.

The error points me to this:

```
<CSPack
  ServiceDefinitionFile="@(TargetServiceDefinition)"
  Output="@(PublishServicePackage)"
  PackRoles="@(Roles)"
  SiteMapping="@(SiteMapping)"
  RoleProperties="@(RoleProperties)"
  CopyOnly="false"
  >
</CSPack>
```